# OpenGL multisample enabling

Tags: opengl

I am trying to use multisampling.

I'm calling `glutInitDisplayMode()` with `GLUT_MULTISAMPLE` flag, then I'm checking if multisampling is available and I received following values: `GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS` = 0 and `GL_SAMPLES` = 1. I suppose it means that multisampling isn't available.

How to solve this issue and make multisampling available?

Comment: what gpu have you got? or just try upgrading the drivers...

Comment: gpu is motherboard embedded...Intel HD Graphics

Comment: so propably is is too old to support multisampling and you cannot fix this... just buy some cheap AMD/NVidia gpu and you can use this feature :)

Comment: I'll try to run programm on some PC with extrernal GPU board

Comment: might be extensions.. try including glew or glee in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If your GPU doesn't support multisampling, then there's nothing you can do, except for buying a better GPU of course...